# Flutter: How to store specifc data from api response in a list

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, get

I have an api which returns json object as response. I have to store all the 'prefix_number'  from response into list to later use it in a dropdown. I am trying to do it but no success.

here is response from api

```
[{prefix_number: 50}, {prefix_number: 51}, {prefix_number: 52}, {prefix_number: 53}, {prefix_number: 54}, {prefix_number: 55}, {prefix_number: 56}, {prefix_number: 57}, {prefix_number: 58}]
```

Here is my a list where i want to store it

```
List<String> prefixList = [];
```

here is my method

```
 Future getNumberPrefixes() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(AppApis.getPrefixesApi);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      // print(data['data'][0]['prefix_number']);
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print("Failed");
    }
  }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
  final body = jsonDecode(res.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final data = body["data"] as List<dynamic>;
  final prefixList = data.map((d) => (d as Map<String, dynamic>)["prefix_number"].toString()).toList();
  print(prefixList);
```

Here is a working example:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=26e63a1baa818af7f3bea41a57eb1556

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: Then update your question to present the exact code you are running and the exact(!) json response, as a string (important). Because as you can see in the linked dartpad, the code I presented works.

Comment: Future getPages() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(AppApis.getPagesApi);
    var response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
      //final list = jsonDecode(data) as List<dynamic>;
      final pageList =
          data.map((d) => (d as Map)["page_name"].toString()).toList();
      print(pageList);
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

Comment: look i am using same approach but no success

Comment: here is the api can you please check it and print  the list of prefix_number........https://api.santra.ae/v1?api=get_prefixes

Comment: Okey. You didn't tell the whole tale.. Updated my answer. Now it works. I tried with your API. And I have updated the dartPad code to reflect the actual data your API give as response. Accept the answer and give a fat thumbs up =)

Comment: Welcome. Next time, present the correct information from the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for you.

```
Future getNumberPrefixes() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(AppApis.getPrefixesApi);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
     
     //ADD Following lines to your code.

      for(int i=0; i< data.length; i++){
        prefixList.add(data[I]["prefix_number"].toString());
      }


      print(data);
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print("Failed");
    }
  }
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Can you share your error?

Comment: i think list is still null

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.